# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common when trying to create a Configuration object

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to interact with my HDFS from within java. When I attempt to create a new Configuration object

Configuration conf = new Configuration();

my application throws this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Preconditions
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationDelta.<init>(Configuration.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationDelta.<init>(Configuration.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:401)
```

I have included the hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh.4.5.0.jar on my java build path and have checked that my hdfs is in fact running hadoop 2.0 cdh 4.5.0.

Am I not including a necessary jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Maven? If not it is advisable to use maven for dependency management.

They have an easy dependency which encapsulates all dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-cdh.4.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

But this particular error is from guava library which you need to include in your classpath. But my guess is you will hit new issues.